# What is the difference between matplotlib bar() and pandas bar() function?

Tags: python, database, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Consider the following dataframe:

```
    index   count   sum
0   4       3372    230
1   4       68855   343
2   2       17948   232
3   5       708     788
4   5       9117    558
```

I want to plot a bar graph by first grouping by 'index' column and for each 'index' plot mean value of 'count'. I can do this by two ways:
Method 1:

```
groups = df.groupby('index')

for name,group in groups:
  print(name)
  print(group)
  plt.bar(name, group['count'].median(), label=name, align='center')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The above code results in:

[image]

Method 2:

```
df.groupby('index')['count'].median().plot.bar()
plt.xlabel('index')
plt.ylabel('count')
plt.title('index')
plt.show()
```

Which results in:

[image]

**1. How can I get unique colour for each bar when using the 2nd method?**
**2. How can I get a continuous graph when using the 1st method (there is a gap between 1st and 2nd)?**

Comment: If you want to first plot to be categorical instead of numerical, use ` plt.bar(str(name), ...)`

Comment: `df.loc[:,['index','count']].groupby('index').mean().T.plot.bar()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard matplotlib bar plot considers the x-axis as numerical when the x-values are numerical. Just change them to string if you want them categorical:

```py
groups = df.groupby('index')
for name, group in groups:
    plt.bar(str(name), group['count'].median(), label=name, align='center')
plt.legend()
```

[image: categorical bar plot in matplotlib]

The pandas bars will have a categorical x-axis, also when the values are numerical.  To color the bars, the `color=` parameter can be used (the default colors have names 'C0', 'C1' etc.):

```py
df.groupby('index')['count'].median().plot.bar(color=['C0', 'C1', 'C2'])
```

[image: pandas bar plot with colors]

Comment: This works when I know the number of bars. In a particular case that I am working on, I do not know the number of bars (number of unique values) that are there. How do I get a different colour for each bar then?

Comment: If you give too many colors, pandas just takes the first ones. E.g `df.groupby('index')['count'].median().plot.bar(color=[f'C{i%10}' for i in range(20)])`. Or `df.groupby('index')['count'].median().plot.bar(color=[plt.cm.tab20(i/20) for i in range(20)])`.

Comment: It worked @JohanC. instead of 20 is used 'len(df['index'].unique())'. Can you tell what does f'C{i%10}' mean. How do I understand that!!

Comment: `f'C{i%10}'` is an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). The value `i % 10` is converted to a string and joined with the rest.  So for i going from 0 to 20, it creates `['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C0', 'C1', 'C2', ...]`

Answer (score 1):

Just specify a list of clolors as an argument to `plot.bar()`

```
df.groupby('index')['count'].median().plot.bar(color=['red', 'green', 'blue'])
```